# mule move pdf ,ppt ,image files from one folder to other

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el

```
 <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester1" resource="file:///#[flowVars.filename]" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
 <object-to-byte-array-transformer/>
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\OUTPUT"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Filewrite" outputPattern="#[flowVars.inpfilename]"/>
```

**Please note below points**

the above flow  will create files (pdf,ppt,image )  with corrupted format in C:\OUTPUT folder

the file i want to move like pdf,ppt,image etc.

anyone suggest solution for that

Comment: There may be some bugs .. I have reported this bugs in jira

Comment: Hi there is no solution for move pdf,ppt files from one folder to other .pls reply

Comment: You ca use file inbound endpoint in that case

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to just move the files with some particular extenstions, this can be done by using File inbound and file outbound endpoints. Your flow should look like as follows

```html
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="*.pdf" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
 </flow>
```

Comment: using <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester1" resource="file:///#[flowVars.filename]" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
 only problem . Not able to move pdf and ppt files